# How to use third party extension in local folder extension..?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new in Magento customization. I want to use the third party extension in my local folder containing extension. How should I proceed..? can any one help me in which files I do changes,step by step way.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.. why do you want to use the 3rd party in your local? Are you looking to customize/change the 3rd party extension?

Comment: my third party extension is in community codepool and I want to use it in local folder containing another extension.

Answer (score 2):

--Edited the answer --
From the comment sit sims that you want to change the namespace of a community extension, so it looks like your own,

Let me guess your module directory

Third Party Module has structure something like this

```
 app\
   code\
     community\
       namespace\
         module\
```

Now you want the module to be moved to the directory which looks like this

```
app\
   code\
      local\
          AW\
```

For this,
You need to move all the `module` under the `AW` folder and rename all the classes inside the `module` by replacing the first word that represents the namespace to `AW`, 
Also you will need to rename the module file located at `app\etc\modules` from `Namespace_Module.xml` to `AW_Module.xml`
I hope this is clear.

Comment: all suggested correct way to me..but my third party extension is in community codepool and I want to use it in local folder containing another extension.

Comment: You can move the Module folder from community to local and edit the app\etc\modules\Module_Name.xml file and change codepool to local.

Comment: this way too done..

Comment: I want to add community module into local containing another module that is AW .

Comment: AW is a namespace and there already exists a module under the namespace if i am not wrong?

Comment: I have edited the answer. please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30299/discussion-between-ashwini-and-taral-patoliya).

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing an exisiting 3rd party module, you should note that it is designed to be either in the local (app/code/local) or in the community code pools (app/code/community). You have to install it where it belongs.

You can of course modify the extension to reside in another code pool, but there is really no reason to do so.

Comment: all suggested correct way to me..but my third party extension is in community codepool and I want to use it in local folder containing another extension.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try to follow the structure of the folder based on the extension.

```
extension folder:
/app
   /code
        /community (local)
```

---

```
your site folder
    /app
       /code
            /community (local)
```

you can follow it and it will work, dont forget to cached or flush.